# How to use C#-Properties in a WCF-Service from Java client

Tags: c#, java, wcf, serialization, properties

we have a C#-Server which runs a WCF-Service. Currently we're implementing some (DataContract)-classes. Now I'm wondering since you can only have private attributes by using C#-Properties, are you still able to use their values in a Java client? What if we're doing some checks in a property getter-method (so we're not just using standard getter/setter)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **public** C# properties of the classes marked by DataContracts will be sent as serialized XML to **any** client of the WCF service. The client technology (java in your example) will deserialize the XML into classes and methods appropriate to java. Here is [a quick overview of soap](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/xml/webservices/) from the java prespective. Simply put, you don't need to worry about whether java supports the concept of "properties"; the java client creation technology will make the appropriate implementation. Any private members will not be serialized.